# Is one allowed to carry an object through an opposite force on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Say one had a strong magnetic force attached to his shoe in a way that was not considered carrying.

Would he be able to point his shoe in a Reshus Harabim and move something with opposite magnetic force so long as he didn't touch the moving object?

Comment: Do you have reason to think this would be different than attractive magnetic force, in a scenario where the thing being moved doesn't move and attach to the magnet?

Comment: I think the point is that the object doesn't cling to the shoe or it would definitely be moving it.

Comment: @andrewmh20 if it was attached yet was not considered part of the original item, then I assume it would be considered carrying as you are carrying that as well.

Comment: Sounds like _blowing_ something into Reshut HaRabbim.

Comment: @DoubleAA that occurred to me as well, although that might be Kocho whereas here it not his power.

Comment: @Yehuda Why is it not his power? He moves the magnet close to the other magnet.

Comment: @DoubleAA yet the actual force that moves the item is from the magnet. If you blow harder, the item will move quicker. If you move the magnet with more speed to the item, it wont change the speed of the escaping object.

Comment: I don't think you get the physics here. Conservation of energy. Any energy in the moved object originated in your foot. Magnets aren't magical.

Comment: Already discussed [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69219/using-the-force-on-shabbat). ;)