# PTIJ: Using the Force on Shabbat

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What halachic considerations must a Jewish Jedi take into account before using the Force on Shabbat?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Off topic, but R' Gil Student discusses this question seriously. https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/jedis-in-halacha (text and YouTube)

Comment: @Micha Berger: Excellent

Answer (score 17):

This is a serious issue that requires real iyun.

We learn of the original star wars in Judges 5:20:

> מִן־שָׁמַ֖יִם נִלְחָ֑מוּ הַכּֽוֹכָבִים֙ מִמְּסִלּוֹתָ֔ם נִלְחֲמ֖וּ עִם־סִיסְרָֽא׃
>
> They fought from heaven, The stars in their courses fought against Sisera.

Now, the stars could not be fighting (with the force) on Shabbos, because the timeframe of the fight is given in Pasuk 2 as:

> בִּפְרֹ֤עַ פְּרָעוֹת֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל בְּהִתְנַדֵּ֖ב עָ֑ם בָּרֲכ֖וּ
> יְהוָֽה׃
>
> When people pay off their loans in Israel, When the people donate; Bless the LORD.

While paying off loans is encouraged, money is muktzeh on Shabbat; thus, this battle (and usage of the force) could not have happened on Shabbat. The fact that the Navi specifies the non-Shabbat piece is meant to teach that the force is Assur on Shabbat. Indeed, [the Rashbam writes](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashbam_on_Pesachim.105a.12?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all):

> שבת אסור... פורס
>
> (On) Shabbat, it is Assur (to do...) Force.

Thus, L'Halacha, the force is Assur on Shabbat.

Answer (score 14):

[W = F * s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29)

As long as the Jedis not moving, there's no work being done. That may be the reason the pasuk says "אל-ייצא איש ממקומו--ביום השביעי"  (Don't move!!)

Comment: Work is done on an object if the force makes the object move. I think the takeaway is the Jedi shouldn't use the force to do telekinesis.

Comment: Is it the Jedi doing the work, or the Force?

Answer (score 9):

On Shabbat, any self respecting Jewdi would use [the Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs#The_Schwartz) , of course.

Comment: We learn in [Mishnah Pesachim 8:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97_%D7%97): Force from the Orlah is like force from the grave.

Answer (score 6):

You can use it in a karmelis, as per the Magen Avraham O.C. 357:10:

> דכחו בכרמלית לא גזרו
>
> No decree was made against Force in a karmelis

Everywhere else, it should be avoided.

On the other hand, when the Jewish Jedi washes for his Shabbos seudos, it's a must (S.A. O.C. 159:7)!

> צָרִיךְ שֶׁיָּבוֹאוּ הַמַּיִם מִכֹּחַ
>
> The water must come through the Force

Answer (score 3):

Rabbeinu Yoda (not to be confused with Rabbeinu Yona) explained:

> Anger, fear, aggression! The dark side of the Force are they ... a
>   Jedi uses the Force for knowledge and defense. Never for attack.

So, the rules seem pretty simple. If you have an Oneg Shabbat, you have joy, not anger.

Fear is hard to eliminate on Shabbat as you have to fear G-d. But, then again, if you know G-d and gain knowledge of G-d, this becomes a permissible use of the Force, so this is allowed on Shabbat.

If a person isolates himself at home all of Shabbat, and avoids interacting with people, he can eliminate the aggression and the dark side and gain benefits from the force, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, our interaction with 'the Force', a type of energy, is not direct. Our connection and ability to work with the Force is through intermediary creatures called 'Midi-chlorians'. They dwell within our cells. Manipulating the Force occurs through manipulating these creatures. This is akin to using your animals for work on Shabbos. It would therefore seem to be prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

Firing missiles down a ventilation shaft that leads to the nuclear core of a spaceship is a mitzvas aseh she'hazman gerama because it has to be done before Darth Vadar escapes.

The passuk says be'moado, from which we derive that the tamid and korban pesach may be brought on Shabbas.

Therefore you may assume that be'moado is also matir using the Force.

However because Darth Vadar is related to the Balrogs so can use an anti-Force Force, it is a sfek sfeika if switching off your flight computer in this situation is the most sensible thing you could possibly do so the Shmiras Shabbas Kehilchaso is noteh le'esor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the force is Avodah Zarah in any case. Chillul Shabbos and Avodah Zarah are both shakul k'neged the whole Torah. Additionally, both carry the penalty of Sekilah. Therefore, there is no reason to differentiate between using the Force on Shabbos and during the week. Hence, no special considerations need to be taken into account in using the force on Shabbos.

Comment: From where do you derive that using the Force is Avodah Zarah?

Comment: @Ze'ev Blumenkrantz Pesach Guide. I kid you not.