# PTIJ: Jedi Using the Force for Kiruv

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Say there is a Jewish Jedi involved in Kiruv work. Is it permissible for such a person to use a Jedi mind trick to convince a non observant Jew to be shomer Shabbos, keep kosher, etc.?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: also about jedi http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69219/759

Comment: This could be a worthwhile serious philosophy question, too.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I was thinking the same thing. I'm considering rephrasing this as non-Star Wars related and asking it as a non-Purim Torah question.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely permissible!

The word "Jedi" is a corruption of the Hebrew word "Yehudi", so all Jedis are Jewish. And, as we know, Jews are responsible for each other - especially when it relates to the performance of mitzvoth.

Mind games and uses of force have been used by Jews throughout history. We see mind force currently used halachically esp. in cases of *siruv* to force men to give their wives a *get*. The procedure is not like what the Jedi use, but, they use emotional and psychological "games". Siruv is meant to be emotionally "taunting".

The idea of using "The Force" should certainly be fine. It's essentially a form of *kavana*, when you think about it. When I was in yeshiva, my rebbis frequently used "The Force", in a modified form. Quite ingenious, actually. If I didn't perform well on my written and oral Gemarrah tests; if I didn't wear my tzizit daily; if I didn't daven, etc. I got bad grades, a bad report card, calls and notes to my parents and a nice spanking from my parents, too. It works!

Mr. Spock, from Star Trek, aka, Leonard Nimoy, ob"m, a Jew, sometimes used the Vulcan mind meld on Captain Kirk, aka William Shattner, another Jew, to force him to do things beneficial for Kirk's health or the safety of the Enterprise.

So we see that use of mind games is absolutely fine, and recommended, in some cases.